# "Position: Fixed" Images on Scroll

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a "about we" page. I've added a navigation bar to up, and added our images in page. When I scroll page to down, the images go on `position: fixed (on css)` navigation bar. How I can do the navigation bar's show over images? My code is:

```
div#nav {
  position: fixed
}

<div id="nav">
<a href="/">Main Page</a>
</div>
<div id="about">
<img src="/me.jpg">
<img src="/friend.jpg">
</div>
```

When user scrolls page down, images show over `nav`. How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you post the screenshot of what it looks like exactly ? Or a more complete example? I cannot reproduce it with this code only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `z-index` to order elements on Z axis :

```
div#nav {
  position: fixed;
  z-index : 999;
}

<div id="nav">
<a href="/">Main Page</a>
</div>
<div id="about">
<img src="/me.jpg">
<img src="/friend.jpg">
</div>
```

`z-index : 3` will show over `z-index : 2` and so on ..

Answer (score 0):

Try below css code

```
body{
  margin-top:40px;
}
#nav {
  position: fixed;
  top:0;
  padding:20px 0;
  background:#FFF;
  width:100%;
}
```